# NOT EXISTS Query with REPLACE Taking Forever to Run

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-performance

I have a stored procedure that analyses a bunch of address data.  My source data has 7k records, and it's taking almost 20min to run.  I narrowed it down to one query.  If I exclude this one query it takes about 4 seconds to run.

The problem query is:

```
SELECT 
    'Invalid City', 
    [Company], 
    [Supplier_No], 
    [Name], 
    [Address], 
    [City], 
    [State], 
    [Zip], 
    [Country] 
  FROM [vendors_raw] vr 
  WHERE 
    ([City]  <> '' AND [City] IS NOT NULL) AND 
    NOT EXISTS( 
        SELECT [cleanCity] 
          FROM [CityStateInfo] 
          WHERE 
            [cleanCity] = REPLACE(  REPLACE(vr.[City], '''', ''), '.', '') 
    )
```

I am getting the correct results, so I don't believe it's a data issue.  `[CityStateInfo]` is pretty straight forward with City, State Zip, and I added a `'cleanCity'` field where I stripped out the comma and periods since some cities include them and some don't.

I included the Execution Plan.  I don't really know how to read them in detail, but I'm pretty sure 5000% of anything is not good.

[image: Execution Plan]

Comment: Any time you use a function in a `where` clause e.g. `replace` you force an entire table scan i.e. indexes can no longer be used - that usually causes slow queries if you have a decent amount of records (although I wouldn't say 7K was many, but it depends on your server specs).

Comment: You *might* find that adding an index on `vendors_raw`, column `city` might speed things up, because then SQL Server can read only that column for the scan - which might be a lot less disk activity than currently.

Comment: It's not a traditional server, but it's still an i7 with 64GB RAM and running on a SSD.  Better/Cleaner way to do what I need?

Comment: The fastest way would be to update your `vendors_raw` table by adding a new column with a *cleaned* city and then index it. That way you don't have to calculate it as part of the query.

Comment: Yes you are recalculating the same static data every time, that is a complete waste of resource and means the query is not `sargable`. Store the cleaned version in the same table and just check for its existence and with an index your query will be orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: You have an equality predicate so adding `OPTION (HASH JOIN)` would probably speed things up compared to doing repeated scans on the inside of a nested loops

Comment: Ok, I added a [cleanCity] to the source table and it's flying!  Taking 15-20s to run now!
I know I thought of doing this, but not sure why I decided not to... Other than the fact I like to make things difficult on myself.